# How to handle background queries on a DB that supports a Web App

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications, architecture

I need some help understanding how I should architect an application. Basically it has two parts.

1. The web app (asp mvc): A user logs into the app, records some data and logs off. The data (login info, user recorded data) is stored locally on my server. It is very simple.
2. The background process: I need a service to receive and send data that is connected with this web app (from #1). I have a 3rd party server that will send user login information (in real time) to my server in which I need to use to update my local DB (this is the same DB that the web app uses for login info). Secondly, I need to run a timed interval process to query the user recorded data plus perform simple logic on it and then send the outcome to this 3rd party server. These steps are all via xml docs.

I am not exactly sure how to attack this problem. I figured I could build a separate web service to do this (it would live on the same server as the web app). Or I could run some sort of `webbackgrounder` (https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder) task solution that is attached to my web app. <strike>Or lastly I could create a SSIS package to do this.</strike> Which route should I go? Thank you for the advice.

Comment: SSIS is the wrong tool for this mix. It is designed for working with sets of data, not onesy/twoseys. There is a cost associated to starting it up as it needs to assert data types match, etc. That's a silly cost to pay just to run some queries